# Запись данных из файла в структуру с++

Tags: c++, файлы, структуры

есть структура

```
struct student
{

    char groupName;
    char surname;
    char name;

    int algerbraMark;
    int discreteMark;
    int programmingMark;
    int englishMark;
};
```

есть файл с которого нужно считать дание и присвоить их даним структуры например:

```
PML14 Stet Roman 91 55 67 24
```

Потом нужно будет сортировать по группе ы сред.ареф балу.

```
int main()
{
    student Student;
     char buffer[100];
     const char ch = '\n';
     int len = 600;
      int strings  = 2 ;//к-ство студентов
    char mass[len][strings];

    ifstream myfile("exampleTest.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        for(int r = 0; r<strings; r++)
            {
                myfile.getline(mass[r], len-1,ch); //Считываем строки в массив
                cout << "String " << r+1 << " = "<< mass[r] << endl; //Выводи строку из массива
            }
```

Пока могу только просто считать строчки

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Student
{
  std::string groupName;
  std::string name;
  std::string surname;

  int algerbraMark;
  int discreteMark;
  int programmingMark;
  int englishMark; 
};

std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& is, Student& s)
{
  is >> s.groupName >> s.name >> s.surname >> s.algerbraMark >> 
  s.discreteMark>> s.programmingMark >> s.englishMark;
  return is;
}

int main()
{
  Student s;
  std::ifstream file("test.txt", std::ios_base::in);
  file >> s;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: а когда много студентов в файле(3+) ?

Comment: http://cpp.sh/522ys